# What is the significance of the font-choice for "Meta"?

Tags: discussion, meta, logo

The original trilogy all use the same distressed serif font for "**meta**".  Does anyone know the significance of this font choice, when all of the rest of the design on the main trilogy sites is clean, solid lines and sans-serif fonts?  Is it purposely meant to be the opposite, like an alternate universe?

Comment: I suspect it's just a stamped blood spatter from all of the fallen (`[status-declined]`) feature requests.

Comment: @TimStone: `[status-declined]` at least go to heaven, though. It's `[status-bydesign]` that's walking the realms between the worlds because the ferry man can't figure out whether they're `[status-wontfix]` or `[status-intentional]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Meta.SO was first created, the team wanted the site to look different from the main Stackoverflow site so you're not confused about which site you're on. The colors on Meta site are desaturated. (This is true for all the other SE Meta sites as well)

As for the red font on Meta.SO, it was chosen so you'd look at it.

Comment: *"...So you're not confused..."*  Except for the people who post a question on Meta asking why the site changed color.

Answer (score 8):

meta is murder.

Comment: Since this just got flagged as "not an answer" -- this is indeed an answer, and not the wrongest one either.

Comment: @balpha Really? This site has different standards than I'm used to then... sorry.  Guess I'll have to recover my flag weight somewhere else.

Comment: @Renesis: Don't worry about it :) Meta is a little more relaxed. And Adam Davis (a.k.a. Pollyanna) is a special case among the special cases :) For reference: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html

Comment: But: [its font is different](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e1d35970b-pi)?

Comment: @Renesis The logo uses the odd font (and here the coloring) directly due to the concept that spending too much time navel gazing is unproductive.  Navel gazing actively kills communities, if not controlled, partitioned, or dealt with in some way.  Meta is murder is Jeff's way of saying, "Yes, we need a meta, but for heaven's sake who cares whether the background colors on the site aren't a pantone match?!  Go out, program, and do something awesome!"  That is the symbolism of the font and coloring.  Meta is not so much a place, as a state of mind.  Specifically, insanity.  *Meta is murder.*

Comment: @Renesis I have found over time that I am often more verbose than I need be in my meandering posts regarding site minutae, and as such I've come to the conclusion that I should attempt to be more brief and concise.  Perhaps I have entered the realm of the opposite extreme with my answer, but I hope you find that these comments bring you to the same conclusion that I have come to hold dear: Ponies coalesce iridescence skeet.  Also, you shouldn't take half of what I say half as seriously as I do, and I rarely take anything here seriously.

Comment: @Adam Now that StackOverflow has become *StackExchange*, a sort-of software platform, has anything about that idea changed? Or, should it?

Comment: @Renesis No. Meta doesn't change. Ever.

Comment: @Renesis Meta serves the same purpose, only with an expanded scope.  1) It acts as an outlet for meta discussion, so endless threads on feature changes don't clog the main site(s) 2) It acts as a community debugging platform, where the community can help Stack Exchange Inc find and resolve bugs 3) It performs customer service functions in terms of account issues, problems with moderators or other community members, problems with general community behavior, etc 4) It allows SE Inc's customers to request features and even 5) Acts as some portion of the stack exchange PR arm. Same old, same old.